# UI-Router not catching non angular URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Why is it when I use `ui.router` with AngularJS and I go to `localhost:14080` it uses the `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home')` to direct me to, `localhost:14080/#/home`, as expected, but when I go to `localhost:14080/home` (without the `/#`) it gives me a 404 error "Not Found".  I would have expected it to redirect me to `localhost:14080/#/home`.

Comment: The `localhost:14080` will be by browser treated as different target than `localhost:14080/home` *(unless we do some magic on server to support so called Html 5 MODE)*. So, browser is in fact asking server for a page.. and there is no such. The root (where we have application) was not reached in that case...

Comment: How would I get angular to include those paths and just route it to the correct one.  For some reason I remember NgRoute doing this. So if I went to '/home' I would get redirected to `/#/home`.